# Following a single user across the screen in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have an iOS app that is linked to Google Analytics via the iOS SDK for GA

I want to find out from GA, how a single user (who I know has signed up at a specific time, and hence would have gone through some signup sequence of screens) has gone from screen to screen post the signup process

What is the best way to do this in GA? I can see a Behaviour Flow in terms of graphical data, where can I see the actual text log or some kind of line by line data for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible with setting user specific values/keys in GAIDictionaryBuilder,

**BUT** based on Privacy policy: http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html

> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service
>   to track or collect personally identifiable information of Internet
>   users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to) associate
>   any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third parties'
>   website(s)) with any personally identifying information from any
>   source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the
>   Service. You will have and abide by an appropriate privacy policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws relating to the collection of
>   information from visitors to Your websites. You must post a privacy
>   policy and that policy must provide notice of your use of a cookie
>   that collects anonymous traffic data.